# Find the law of a random variable knowing two others

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $(v_i)_{i\in\mathbf{N}^*}$ be a sequence of independent and identically distributed continuous random variables. Let $s$ be a discrete random variable with values in $\mathbf{N}^*$, and let $H := \sum_{i=1}^s v_i$. Let's assume that $s$ is almost surely finite. Knowing distributions of $H$ and $s$, how can we find the distribution of the $v_i$'s ? (That is, of $v_1$, the $v_i$'s being identically distributed.)

I should mention that even if I am interested in theoretical solutions, I am more interested into numerically tractable solutions.

*Remark*. $H$ and $s$ are not supposed to be independent.

*Example of my problem.* I am trying to figure out the probability distribution of the lifetime of a certain item. The only data I am being given though is the stock register on a monthly basis. So every month I know how many new items ($N$) are sent in production to replace "dead" items, and how many working hours there was in total for that month ($H$). If $V$ is the distribution for a given item then we have :

$$V_1^* +V_2^* + V_1 + \ldots V_{N-1} = H$$

where the transformation $V \mapsto V^*$ accounts for the fact that prior to the first movement in the stock some hours are done by an item at the end of its life and similarly the last movement of stock does not count for a full life but only those hours in the observed month. If one knows $V$, one can easily implement $V^*$ (and one can check that $V_1^*$ and $V_2^*$ share the same distribution).

So basically the problem initially proposed, ignoring $V^*$, is a subproblem, somewhat simpler, of the original one. As a matter of fact, recovering $V$ from $V^*$, whether analytically or by computation, seems more difficult. $V \mapsto V^*$ may be injective, but with real data it sems really difficult to implement.

Comment: This may or may not be useful: The characteristic function of $H$ can be written in terms of the characteristic function of the $v_i$. $$\phi_H(t) = \mathbb{E} e^{itH} = \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[e^{itH} \mid s]]  = \mathbb{E}[(\phi_{v_1}(t))^s].$$

Comment: Yes, I remarked that, so that getting the characteristic function of $v_1$ is theoretically possible by inverting the function $x\mapsto \sum_{k\geq 1} \mathbf{P}[s=k] x^k$. Put practically (in fact, in my case, numerically) it is useless for me. I should have precised that I even if I am interested in theoretical solutions, I am more interested into numerically tractable solutions.

Comment: Could you give an example of your problem?

Comment: @AlgorithmsX I will update my question with an example of my problem

Comment: @AlgorithmsX I updated my question with an example of my problem

Comment: @EricFlorentNoube Thank you. I have a few clarification questions. I am going to assume that you are working in a grocery store for the sake of these questions, but these questions should apply to all stores. What exactly is your definition of an item? Do you know how much of N is from each item, or, in other words, do you know how many cans of a specific brand and flavor of soup you get, or do you just get the total number of cans of soup? Are "dead" items items that you no longer have due to having to throw them away or people buying them, or are they something else?